# Was sind »Knochenscheiben« im Kontext von Geld?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> »Geld soll aus Knochenscheiben gemacht sein, da es dann einem Verfallsprozess unterliegt und im Falle der Hortung so unerträglich zu stinken beginnt, dass es sehr bald weitergegeben wird.«

Was meint der Autor hier mit *Geld soll aus Knochenscheiben gemacht sein*? Ist das als Zeichen für das Alter des Geldes zu verstehen oder was?

Comment: Weil es im Wörterbuch steht, und ich davon ausgehe dass die Frage demnächst als Off-Topic geschlossen wird.

Comment: @Hans-Jakob warum als off Topic

Comment: From Help- Center: *If your question could be answered by a dictionary, a grammar book, or another general reference, consult these.*

Comment: das hängt vom  Kontext ab so Wörterbücher haben nichts zu tun hier

Comment: @user26646: Die Kontextabhängigkeit sehe ich nicht, das Wort ist analog wie *Brotgescheibe* gebildet, eine Scheibe aus einem Knochen eben.

Comment: Zwei Tipps: Aussagekräftige Titel sind sinnvoll. Das Kopieren einer geschlossenen Frage unter anderem Titel ist es nicht. Die kontextabhängigkeit der Bedeutung ist - siehe meinen Kommentar zur anderen Frage - eher fraglich.

Comment: @guidot die Frage hier ist unterschiedlich

Comment: Welcher Autor? Welches Werk? Wenn Dir die Quelle vorliegt, bitte zitiere sie anständig: Autor, Titel, Erscheinungsjahr. Das ist oft hilfreich.

Comment: Auch wenn man die Frage schließen will halte ich die Verbesserung des Titels für eine gute Idee, damit man in 3 Tagen, wenn man den Titel wieder sieht, sich erinnert, worum es ging.

Comment: @userunknown Sie haben Recht ich will den Titel hinfügen

Comment: Please do not repost a question that the community had closed as *off topic*. Instead, make an edit to the previously closed question. This will make it enter a reopen review queue. It will be reopened if the edit was substantial enough to make the question fit to  our Q&A format. Listen to people's comments, and ask for help if you get stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das Zitat »Geld soll aus Knochenscheiben gemacht sein, da es dann einem Verfallsprozess unterliegt und im Falle der Hortung so unerträglich zu stinken beginnt, dass es sehr bald weitergegeben wird.« stammt vom antiken griechischen Philosophen [Diogenes von Sinope](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogenes_von_Sinope).

Überlieferter Kernpunkt seiner Lehre war vor allem die Bedürfnislosigkeit, d.h. dass der Mensch nur den Elementarbedürfnissen wie Essen, Trinken, Kleidung, Behausung und Geschlechtsverkehr folgen soll. Alle anderen Bedürfnisse sind abzulehnen und der Mensch soll ihnen auch nicht folgen.

Dem gehört entsprechend auch das Streben nach Reichtum an.

Diogenes erkannte die Nützlichkeit des Geldes als Tauschmittel, argumentierte aber wie gesagt dagegen es zu horten und anzusammeln, denn dies widerspricht seiner Lehre der Bedürfnislosigkeit. Geld das sich somit durch seine organische Struktur (auch Knochen verrotten) nicht zur Lagerung, sondern nur zum schnellen Tausch eignet, ist seiner Meinung nach das einzige, das verwendet werden sollte

Heute wird dieses Zitat oft in anderen Zusammenhängen verwendet. Etwa der [Verlangung von Zinsen](https://books.google.de/books?id=yXZ3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT83&lpg=PT83&dq=Geld%20soll%20aus%20Knochenscheiben%20gemacht%20sein&source=bl&ots=ZfEkoM9Ns6&sig=PfB84bKLB8iUsAVjS-TZEyBwCT0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiH8Li-jeHfAhUjpYsKHYUNBCgQ6AEwAXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=Geld%20soll%20aus%20Knochenscheiben%20gemacht%20sein&f=false), [neuen Zahlungsmodellen](https://www.risknet.de/wissen/rezensionen/geld-war-gestern/9dd903b32a84ba65b9e443d777cdc86b/), etc.

Comment: meinen Sie velliecht, dass wenn Geld gespart wird, wird es verottet als Knochenscheibe, wenn wir Sport nicht praktizieren, werden sie verottet

Comment: Lauter dicke Fragezeichen bei der OP-Q, dann eine A wie diese lesen, und es geht ein Licht auf. Thx +1 (Für den Q body, der title ist nach wie vor ??)

Answer (score 1):

Hierbei wird

> machen

in dem Sinne von

> anfertigen

verwendet. Die Forderung impliziert, dass das hergestellte Geld vergänglich sein soll. Insbesondere die begrenzte Haltbarkeit soll dazu führen, dass das Geld recht bald wieder ausgegeben wird.

Die Forderung widerspricht der heutigen Praxis, Münzen aus Metall zu verwenden. Sie ist wohl auch nicht wörtlich zu nehmen, da der Verfallsprozess unabhängig von der Hortung stattfindet. Daher denke ich, dass es eine sarkastische Forderung ist.

Comment: Der Verfallsprozess ist zwar unabhängig von der Hortung, aber der Witz der Sache ist doch, dass ein Anreiz geschaffen wird, das Geld schnell wieder auszugeben, weil man dann nicht mehr unter der Verrottung zu leiden hat.